# Pesquisar por lista de ids no mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, array, tsql

Alguém sabe como pegar vários elementos de uma base de dados usando um array que contenha todos os id de pesquisa??
PHP/MySQL

```
static function list($ids){
    $wa = "";
    foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
      $wa .= " e_produto.id = {$value} OR";
    }
    $wa = substr($wa,0,-2);
    $wa = ($wa!="")?"OR $wa":"";
    ////------------
    $myid = User::id();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE $wa;";
    $retorno = DB::dbQuery($query,$carrinhoArr);

    return $retorno;
  }
```

É a solução provisoria que consegui. Mas existe uma forma "mais correta"?

Comment: Teria como dar um exemplo de código no mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar desta forma no momento da consulta.

```
$ids = array('1', '2', '3');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (" . implode(', ', $ids) . ")";

// Saída
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei Encontrando a resposta!

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp?fbclid=IwAR2M8oAroid908S65C9wgiI4nob921uOYeVcbJd6cUBRsCq-HIr8CRfjs0E